# Laravel - Retrieving a username using two tables with both having the userID

Tags: php, laravel

What's up fellow StackOverflow users,

The thing that I am trying to accomplish is to basicly retrieve the username of someone with only the availability of the person's user_id.

My project is using two different tables, one is for the articles, and the other one is for the user-data.

I am currently displaying all of the articles into a view, but I also want to display the author's name of each post, with only access to the user_id.

*The method inside of my controller which I'm using:*

```
    public function index() {
    $posts = Index::all();

    return view('index', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

*The view where I want to display the username in to:*

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="col-12">
            @if(!Auth::check())
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item mb-3"><h1 class="h1">Become a member now</h1>
                    <h5 class="h5">Discuss your favourite topics with the internet</h5>
                    <a href="{!! url()->current() !!}/register"><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Get started</button></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            @endif
            @if(count($posts) > 0)
                <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach ($posts as $post)
                        <li class="list-group-item" style="text-decoration: none;">b/{{ strtolower($post->subbie) }} · Posted by u/Test</li>
                        <a href="{!! url()->current() !!}/s/{{ $post->subbie }}/{{ $post->id }}">
                            <li class="list-group-item mb-3" style="text-decoration: none;"><h5 class="h5">Tekst: {{ $post->body }}</h5></li>
                        </a>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @else
                <h1>Helaas zijn er nog geen artikels beschikbaar</h1>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Do you have relations set up between User and Post?

Comment: I don't think I have, where do I set that up? 
*Edit: The user_table uses: "id" and the post_table uses: "user_id"

Comment: In your models. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as you said you have user_id in articles you can add relation to  article model

```
class your_article_model extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

and get all users with articles by adding `with()`

```
$posts = Index::with('user')->get();
```

you can find detail in laravel documention :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: I am trying to display a name with your lines of code in my view: {{ $post->user->name }} gives me the error:
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: @SanderPlomp after $posts = Index::with('user')->get(); put dd($posts)
check if user exist in $posts

Comment: I want to thank you for your time, it's working now.

Comment: @SanderPlomp you're welcome 
sorry I couldn't check for days